# Nginx real client IP to TCP stream backend

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use Nginx as proxy for my TCP daemon, to make Nginx be SSL/TLS frontend, as well as load control.

My backend app needs real client IP, and this is a problem.

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     3333;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2222;
    }
}
```

I found one solution in docs:

```
proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
```

But it's too complicated:

> "In order for this parameter to work, it is necessary to run nginx
>   worker processes with the superuser privileges and configure kernel
>   routing table to intercept network traffic from the proxied server."

Is there any other way to pass $remote_addr to backend?

I tried modify client message body using sub_filter, send http headers, etc. But all of this can work only with http context, not with stream unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, there are only two solutions: `proxy_bind` and `proxy_protocol`.

#### proxy_bind

As you quoted from the documentation, the work processes will need *superuser* privileges. Obviously. this not a best practice. Additionally, it might cause connection issues back to the remote clients.

Assuming the Nginx is running as the `nginx` user, run this command to give it permissions.

```
usermod -aG sudo nginx
```

#### proxy_protocol

This solution requires the upsteam destination (e.g. the backend app) accepts PROXY protocol.

```
stream {
    server {
        listen         3333;
        proxy_pass     127.0.0.1:2222;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

The above solutions assume the Nginx server is the entry point to the network. If there is a edge device (e.g. load balancer), it is very likely it is changing the source IP. In this case, you will need to enable *proxy protocol* on the edge device and enable `proxy_protocol` listener in the `server` block.  I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.

```
stream {
    server {
        listen            3333 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass        127.0.0.1:2222;
        proxy_protocol    on;
        set_real_ip_from  $proxy_protocol_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,   I tried this but it is not allowed. I get an error:
   nginx: [emerg] "set_real_ip_from" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @asmoljo check my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873393/nginx-real-client-ip-to-tcp-stream-backend/47330299#comment132209412_47687962

Comment: Can't get it to work - ...`"host not found in set_real_ip_from "$proxy_protocol_addr"...`

Answer (score 6):

**My setup**:

1. Nginx stream module as Tcp proxy for ssh and https
2. Nginx http module to serve my content

**My requirement**:
Having the real client ip inside access.log (instead of 127.0.0.1 from stream module) and also for geoblocking

**My solution**:

1. Activate proxy_protocol (to add the additional information in the requests)
2. add "proxy_procotol" in http listen directive (for the http server to accept)
3. add extra proxy between stream module and ssh to remove proxy_protocol for ssh being able to read
4. replace "$remote_addr" with "$proxy_protocol_addr" in access.log

For geoblocking you also have to use proxy_protocol_addr, but i'll omit describing this here to keep it short.

nginx.conf:

```
...
stream {

    upstream ssh {
        server 127.0.0.1:2222;
    }

    upstream https {
        server 127.0.0.1:444;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
        default ssh;
        "TLSv1.2" https;
        "TLSv1.3" https;
        "TLSv1.1" https;
        "TLSv1.0" https;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        proxy_protocol on;
        ssl_preread on;
    }

    server {
        listen 2222 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass 192.168.2.76:22;
    }
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$proxy_protocol_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    ...
    server {
        listen 444 ssl proxy_protocol;
    ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"set_real_ip_from" directive should be the address/CIDR of the edge device

```
stream {
    server {
        listen            3333 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass        127.0.0.1:2222;
        proxy_protocol    on;
        set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "set_real_ip_from" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @MikeG.  install stream_realip_module

Comment: Can you please point me to the doc how to do it in Ubuntu 20? I struggled for many hours without any success :(

Comment: @MikeG. This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-stream_realip_module configuration parameter.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_realip_module.html

Comment: @MikeG. However, if you use the latest 1.22.1 from the nginx repo, it's prebuilt with this module, you can check the build options with `nginx -V`.